# Classic ASP, Windows Auth (w/PassThrough), Anon Disabled, AppPool ID w /Service Account, STILL double hop issue to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, iis, asp-classic

I know this is a frequently asked question, but either many aren't answered, or are not my particular issue.  So, at the risk of being redundant:

1 - Classic ASP Site.

2 - Windows Authentication enabled (test settings button all successful)

3 - Anonymous Authentication disabled

4 - Passthrough Authentication enabled

5 - AppPool ID set to domain\domainUserAccount

6 - domain\domainUserAccount set as LOGIN in SQL Server Security

7 - domain\domainUserAccount set as user in Database.

With all these options set, the site should use my own login creds to access IIS site resources.  And it should use the AppPool Active Directory User service account to access SQL Server database.  Right?

But, I get the dreaded:

```
Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0 error '80040e4d'
Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.
```

I've tried everything I can think of, and usually the above solves the problem.  But not this time.

Any ideas or advice on what to look for?

**EDIT: If I give it an Active Directory service account in IIS in "Connect as... --> Specific User", it runs fine, but only if I give that service account Read/Write access to Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/V4.0xxx/Temporary ASP.NET Files.  This is somehow a monumental security risk for our Network Admin, even though I have explained that this is perfectly normal for an IIS/ASP service account to be able to R/W this temp files folder in order to run properly.**

Comment: Was that the penultimate solution for you or did you ever find another work around?

Comment: That was 3 years ago, and I'm not sure which project I was working on at the time.  However, I believe you might take step "4 - Passthrough Authentication enabled", and instead of passthrough, use "Connect As..." and assign the same Active Directory account as the AppPool ID.  Doing this, however, your app will connect as that AD service account, not as the actual user using it.

Comment: Thank you for getting back.  A year into a project this feature was just now requested,  I will give this a shot when I get to that segment and report back.